# Shortcut to check if $a^b<c^d$ for $2\leqslant a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{N}$ and $(a-c)(b-d)<0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Notice that the phrasing of the problem rejects the trivially possible, trivially impossible and equivalent cases.

Here is my attempt.
\begin{eqnarray}
a^b&<&c^d\\
b\ln a&<&d\ln c\\
\frac{\ln a}a&<&\frac{cd}{ab}\frac{\ln c}c
\end{eqnarray}
We know that
$$a\stackrel{1}{>}c\geqslant3\stackrel{2}{>}e\implies\frac{\ln a}a<\frac{\ln c}c\\
\because f=\frac{\ln x}x\rightsquigarrow f'=\frac{\ln(e/x)}{x^2}\stackrel{2}{<}0.$$ So if we also have $\frac{cd}{ab}\geqslant1$
$$\rightsquigarrow\frac bd\leqslant\frac ca\stackrel{1}{<}1,\tag{$\star$}$$ the inequality follows.

Now remain the cases

1. $\frac ca<\frac bd<1$ (where we consider $a>c\geqslant3$ and $\frac ca<\frac bd$)
2. $\frac 23\geqslant\frac ca=\frac 2a$
3. $\frac bd>\frac ca=\frac c2\geqslant\frac32$ (where we consider $\frac bd>\frac ca>1$ and notice that the subcase $c>a\geqslant3>e$ is rejected because it guarantees the opposite of the inequality)
4. $\frac ca\geqslant\frac bd>1$ (where we consider $c>a$ and $\frac bd\leqslant\frac ca$)

I am wondering if there are similar quick strict shortcuts that only involve products and ratios of the variables $a,b,c,d$ for the other $4$ cases. If not, then I would like to know why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd eliminate the symmetric problems and reduce the number of cases by requiring $a<c$ and $b>d$.

Comment: What do the little numbers on top of the inequality symbols mean?

Comment: I refer to the inequalities using them so it's easy to see how the result comes about.

Answer (score 1):

One way of determining if $a^b < c^d$ is by actually computing $a^b$ and $c^d$. With a computer, this is usually feasible, although depending on the size of your integers, it would probably be more efficient to approximate the log of either side.

Based on how you asked the question, I'm guessing that you want to be able to determine by hand whether $a^b < c^d$ as quickly as possible. This sort of approximation is a relatively common task on math competitions, and from my experience there is no simple by-hand algorithm. However, usually the best way to determine whether $a^b < c^d$ is to make approximations of both sides by simpler exponents. For instance, say we want to determine whether
$2^{78} $ or $7^{27}$ is larger. Since $2^{10} > 10^3$ and $7^2 <50$, we have
$$2^{78} > 10^{3*7}*2^{8} = 10^{21}*2^8$$
$$7^{27} < 50^{13}*7 = 5^{13}*10^{13}*7$$
We have that $5^5$ is just under $3200 = 2^5*10^2$, so
$$7^{27} < 2^{10} * 10^{17} * 5^3 * 7$$
and then we can establish that
$$7^{27} < 2^{10} * 10^{17} * 5^3 * 7 < 10^{21} * 2^8 < 2^{78}$$
since $2^2 * 5^3 * 7 = 350 < 10^4$. This method always requires a bit of guess and check, and the hardest part is finding the right approximations of each power.

I would be surprised if there were a simple by hand algorithm to determine $a^b < c^d$ for all integers $a,b,c,d$, since any such algorithm can probably be reduced to an approximation of $\log$ by rational numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious way would be to check whether b * log a < d * log c. And then use Euclid’s extended algorithm to find better and better approximations of log d by log an and solve it.

And then calculate the exponential on both sides, and this might give you a result. Just an idea, shouldn’t be hard to work out.